# Let $H,K$ be finite groups , if for any finite group $G$ , $h(G,K)=h(G,H)$ holds , then is it true that $i(G,H)=i(G,K)$ for any finite group $G$ ?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $G,H$ be two groups , let $h(G,H)$ be the number of all group homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$ and $i(G,H)$ be the no. of all injective group homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$ . I know the relation $h(G,H)=\sum_{N \lhd G } i (G/N , H)$ . Now let $H,K$ be finite groups , if for any finite group $G$ ,  $h(G,K)=h(G,H)$ holds  , then is it true that  $i(G,H)=i(G,K)$ for any finite group $G$ ?

Comment: Do you know any examples where $H$ and $K$ are different, but $h(G,K)=h(G,H)$ for all $G$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : No ...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161733  is similar, but is based on counting homomorphisms in the reversed direction i.e. from $H$ and $K$ to $G$. In that case, it turns out that there are no finite examples of nonisomorphic groups with the same homomorphism counts, and I would guess that the same is true in your case.

Comment: I think here the words "for any finite group $G$" means a finite group $G$ which has the property $h(G,K)=h(G,H),$ *not* for all finite group $G.$ (I may be wrong also)

Comment: @I mean that for any finite group $G$ , $h(G,H)=h(G,K)$ holds ...

Comment: $i(G,H) = h(G,H)-\sum_{N \lhd G, N\ne 1 } i (G/N , H)$, so induct on the order of $G/N$.

Comment: Rereading your question I wondered if you considered the implications of $i(G,H) = i(G,K)$ for $G$ being $H$ or $K$?

Comment: @j.p. : yup , as $i(H,K)=i(H,H) \ne 0$ and $i(K,H)=i(K,K) \ne 0$ , so there exist a monomorphism from $H$ to $K$ and also a monomorphism from $K$ to $H$

Comment: @j.p. : yes off-course ; $H=K$ :)

Comment: @SaunDev: So you can rephrase your question slightly simpler in the style of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161733/can-i-recover-a-group-by-its-homomorphisms